# Multiple sign in one DocuSign embedded sign

Tags: docusignapi

Can we send a DocuSign with multiple signature? I need to send a DocuSign with multiple signature field. One recipient has to sign one particular signature field and then send the same DocuSign has to another recipient and he has to sign other signature field keeping the previous recipient signature and so on and I have to set receipt programmatically. Is it possible? and how can I implement that? Is it possible on embedded signing?

Comment: buyer has to sign the docusign first then forward to seller to sign the same docusign agreement.How to do that programatically?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, You add two recipients, two signers. You set the first one to routiner_order 1 and the second one to routing_order 2 to force the particular order. Here is some C# code, not sure which lang you use:

```
// Create a signer recipient to sign the document, identified by name and email
            // We set the clientUserId to enable embedded signing for the recipient
            // We're setting the parameters via the object creation
            Signer signer1 = new Signer
            {
                Email = signerEmail,
                Name = signerName,
                ClientUserId = signerClientId,
                RoutingOrder = "1", 
                RecipientId = "1"
            };
            Signer signer2 = new Signer
            {
                Email = signerEmail,
                Name = signerName,
                ClientUserId = signerClientId,
                RoutingOrder = "2", 
                RecipientId = "2"
            };

            // Create signHere fields (also known as tabs) on the documents,
            // We're using anchor (autoPlace) positioning
            //
            // The DocuSign platform seaches throughout your envelope's
            // documents for matching anchor strings.
            SignHere signHere1 = new SignHere
            {
                AnchorString = "/sn1/",
                AnchorUnits = "pixels",
                AnchorXOffset = "10",
                AnchorYOffset = "20"
            };
            // The DocuSign platform seaches throughout your envelope's
            // documents for matching anchor strings.
            SignHere signHere2 = new SignHere
            {
                AnchorString = "/sn2/",
                AnchorUnits = "pixels",
                AnchorXOffset = "10",
                AnchorYOffset = "20"
            };
            // Tabs are set per recipient / signer
            Tabs signer2Tabs = new Tabs
            {
                SignHereTabs = new List<SignHere> { signHere2 }
            };
            signer2.Tabs = signer2Tabs;
            Tabs signer1Tabs = new Tabs
            {
                SignHereTabs = new List<SignHere> { signHere1 }
            };
            signer1.Tabs = signer1Tabs;
```

Comment: I have buyer with routing order1 and seller with routing order 2 .                               
Buyer  sign the embedded docusign from my php application(I will save the status of buer agreement signed) , after buyer sign it will automatically send to seller in email for signing. How will we know in the application whether seller signed the agreement what he got through email? how will I check in the code?

Comment: you should use a webhook. It's called DocuSign Connect. You need a URL in your app that DocuSign calls back to with the information to tell you an envelope was complete. 
Start here - https://developers.docusign.com/platform/webhooks/ and let me know if not clear

Comment: Using envelopID , can we get the receipt/signer status whether they signed or not from email?

Comment: yes, but that would be polling. You will have to keep checking the same endpoint and it's inefficient and also not allowed. It's better to use a webhook and we tell you when it was signed.

Comment: Buyer is doing embedded docusign and  send to seller? how to do docusign connect in php so that we can get the signed status of seller? Can we get the buyer signed  docusign send to seller in embedded view in seller dashboard for signing? how to configure connect and php code for docusign webhook?

Comment: how can I do envelope level docusign connect

Comment: https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-common-api-tasks-add-a-connect-webhook-to-your-envelopes had code examples in 6 langs.